Change of variable formula for double integral on a square
I have the following integral:
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}dxdy f(x)g(y)h(x-y),$$
and I want to change variables. I decided to use the following:
$$x = \frac{1}{2}(u+v) \quad \mbox{and} \quad y = \frac{1}{2}(u-v)$$
In this case, $x-y = v$. My question is about the domain of the new integral in the $u-v$ variables. Using:
$$u = x+y \quad \mbox{and} \quad v = x-y,$$
is it true to say that the new domain is $-2 \le u \le 2$ and $-1 \le v \le 2$? In other words, does is the following identity:
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}dxdy f(x)g(y)h(x-y) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-2}^{2}du \int_{-1}^{2}dv f((u+v)/2)g((u-v)/2)h(v)$$
true?
